# can't attach jQuery tableditor into my table

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I downloaded jQuery tableditor but I can't use.
I added JS files into my page:

```
<script src="../assets/jquery-tabledit-1.2.3/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/jquery-tabledit-1.2.3/jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#sales_table').Tabledit({
            url: 'example.php',
            editButton: false,
            deleteButton: false,
            hideIdentifier: true,
            columns: {
                identifier: [0, 'id'],
                editable: [[2, 'firstname'], [3, 'lastname']]
            }
        });
    </script>
```

And this is my table:

```
        <table id="sales_table" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td id="firstname" name="firstname">a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

But nothing happened, and can't edit the table.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful to check the developer console of your browser and provide any errors (if any) that are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong index values for the editable columns and you also need an identifier column. The identifier column is hidden by the call to `Tableedit`.

It also appears that you are not referencing the main jquery library (at least in the example you've provided):
[JQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js)

See this for a working example:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/3ae4pay6/1/)

You'll need to read the documentation if you want to update the table and carry out any other functionality:

[Tableedit Docs](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Creating-A-Live-Editable-Table-with-jQuery-Tabledit.html)

**Html**

```
<table id="sales_table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="identifier" name="identifier">1</td> 
      <td id="firstname" name="firstname">John</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#sales_table').Tabledit({
  url: 'example.php',
  editButton: false,
  deleteButton: false,
  hideIdentifier: true,
  columns: {
    identifier: [0, 'id'],
    //Note that I've modified the column index values.
    editable: [[1, 'firstname'], [2, 'lastname']]
  }
});
```

Comment: sir, can you help me with the example.php I am having trouble, is it a normal php update query where we return json_encode ?

Comment: You should ask a new question as the answer would not be directly relevant to the current question.

Comment: I asked a new one here is the link please help  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726371/jquery-tableditor-update-without-a-submit-button)[link]

Comment: still waiting you response here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726371/jquery-tableditor-update-without-a-submit-button

Comment: I'm not very familiar with php so you'll have to wait for someone else to answer. This question was jquery, which I am familiar with.